# Unable to connect Socket.io server from windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms, socket.io

Am developed socket io server code using node. it's working fine am able to connect with react application.
Now am trying to connect the server through windows form application. It's not connected.
In windows application am using SocketIoClientDotNet for connect server.
am used the below code.

```
Quobject.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableList<string> trans = Quobject.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableList.Create<string>("websocket");
IO.Options options = new IO.Options();
options.IgnoreServerCertificateValidation = true;
options.Transports = trans;     
options.Host = "http://192.168.0.125";
options.Port = 3009;
options.ForceNew = true;
options.AutoConnect = true;
                
var socket = IO.Socket("http://192.168.0.125:3009",options);
   socket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, () =>
     {
         socket.Emit("join_room", "123456");
         MessageBox.Show("Connect.....");
    });
socket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, (Data) => Console.WriteLine("Connect Error: " + Data));
socket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, (Data) => Console.WriteLine("Connect TImeout Error: " + Data));
socket.On(Socket.EVENT_ERROR, (Data) => Console.WriteLine("Error: " + Data));
```

I get the below error :

> Connect Error:Quobject.SocketIoClientDotNet.Client.SocketIOException:
> timeout

Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks for advance.

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: yes i got timeout error while i used the below code.

socket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, (Data) => Console.WriteLine("Connect Error: " + Data));

                socket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, (Data) => Console.WriteLine("Connect TImeout Error: " + Data));

                socket.On(Socket.EVENT_ERROR, (Data) => Console.WriteLine("Error: " + Data));

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show that code and also the exact, full error message you received.

Comment: Can you check now.

Comment: The main reasons for timeouts like this are probably network issued- e.g. you got the address of the server wrong in the code, or there is a firewall blocking the connection somewhere, or the server isn't running, or possibly the server is running but isn't working properly for some reason. There isn't enough information in your question for us to be able to do anything more than just speculate like that, unfortunately